# Character limit on .bat arguments

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've written a batch file to mimic the "New Folder with Selection" behavior from MacOS. Doing this on the context-menu (with custom items) was troubling, so I went with the "Send to" approach.

[image: screenshot of "Send to" in context-menu]

I select some files and send them to a .bat file, and in the file, I do the necessary operations:

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "def=New Folder"
set "name=%def%"

set /p name=Folder name: 

set count=1

:loop
if not exist "%name%" goto :continue
set /a count+=1
set "name=%name% (%count%)
goto :loop

:continue
mkdir "%name%"
FOR %%A IN (%*) DO move "%%~A" "%cd%\\%name%"
```

This works really fine, until I hit a character limit. For example, I have created a folder "test" in C. I have 650 empty files:

```
001.txt
002.txt
003.txt
004.txt
005.txt
...
```

When I try to send these (650) files to my batch file, it doesn't work. I can send 504 files, but not 505.

The issue is not about the count. I have tested sending different length file names/path, and the count changes depending on the file name/path. There must be some character limit. When I print `%*`, I get (a space seperated paths/list?)

```
C:\test\001.txt C:\test\002.txt C:\test\003.txt ...
```

The length of it is 8063.

I changed the folder name "test" to "te" to decrease the length. Then I could send 576 files. 577 breaks it. Again 576 files amount to 8063 chars.

Then I changed "te" to just "t" and tested again. This time I could send 620 files which amounts to 8059 characters. Sending 621 files breaks it. So I'm going to guess here and say that the limit seems to be around 8064.

If the total character length of all arguments (paths) exceeds this limit, batch file doesn't work.

Why is this? Is this documented anywhere? Is there a way to get around this?

---

Additionally, I'm not sure if this is a batch related problem. It could be related to "Send to". It might be not even calling the bat file because of the character length. I don't know how to test this.

Comment: Did you not [search?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/830473/command-prompt-cmd-exe-command-line-string-limitation) `:)` you have a character limit of 8191 on a single line in batch.

Comment: Also, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22992190/expansion-character-at-position-8191-in-for-loop-in-batch-script-produces-undesi), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217134/file-size-and-line-length-limits-for-windows-batch-files) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+character+limit)

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Well, my actual question is the third one (Is there a way to get around this?), but I guess there isn't?

Comment: Yes there is, see the links in second comment... additionally, you could have gotten name of file only without path which will help a bit as you'll save a minimum of 6 characters per filename.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you drag your files onto the batch and not just read it from the folder where the files exist? `for %%i in (*.txt) do ...`

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Sorry if I wasn't being clear. I'm selecting the files and sending them to my batch file (right-click -> Send to -> New Folder with Selection.bat) I want it to be accessibly from anywhere. I need to make this work the way it is with this character limit. And honestly, my batch knowledge is limited. I don't know how to impleted the solutions provided in the pages you linked.

Comment: I still don't think you are explaining this good enough. Why can't you just send the folder only which will only send one item instead of hundreds of files.

Comment: You could try some different scripting language: VBScript or Powershell. With them you can hit a maximum limit for a Windows command line - 32768 characters.

Comment: @Squashman I started doing this to solve a specific problem (grouping 9k+ log files) then remembered about MacOS feature "New Folder with Selection". So I wanted it to be a more general solution that I can use with any type of files/cases. So the problem shifted from specific (grouping my logs files) to general (mimicing MacOS feature). An example case would be grouping 100 files into, say, 4 folders. I'd select 25 files and send them to the bat file. If I have to create a folder and send that to the bat, that would defeat the purpose of this bat file/feature :)

Comment: @Squashman obviously because he could want to select only part of these files. The whole reason of this script is to move selected files to a new folder.

Comment: @montonero, please explain the caveats of creating drag and drop PowerShell scripts to the user. I did this years ago when PowerShell came out and I posted alot on the TechGuy forums. There are two major hurdles. Signed scripts and a registry entry for the drop handler.

Comment: @Squashman I believe developing of Powershell scripts is a too wide theme to discuss it in comments. BTW a drop handler is not required in case of `Send To`.